# javascript to open all html links in a new tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to be able to set, in javascript, all html page links to open in a new tab, how can I do that?

Can it be attributed to the div "links"?

Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Negócios</title>


<script type="text/javascript">
</script>



</head>

<body>


<div id="links">
<p><a href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/ivendi.maringa2/" data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/group.php?id=472352436193468" aria-owns="js_1j" aria-haspopup="true" id="js_1k">MARINGÁ - NEGÓCIOS</a></p>
<p><a href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/638497612850047/" data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/group.php?id=638497612850047" aria-owns="js_1l" aria-haspopup="true" id="js_1m">MONTES CLAROS - NEGÓCIOS</a><br>
</p>
<p><a href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/aggape/" data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/group.php?id=538358279511007" aria-owns="js_1r" aria-haspopup="true" id="js_1s">Sucesso Empresarial</a></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to do that without using the target attribute in the HTML. I have too many links, also, I want to learn how to do that.

Comment: By using the target attribute?

Comment: just give the a element a `target="_blank"`

Comment: Why do you need to do this with Javascript?  Why not set the target attribute to _blank?  `<a href="somelink" target="_blank">My Line</a>`

Comment: Like other says target="_blank" but if you whant with javascript `window.open(url,'_blank');` but is not good solution.

Comment: If you have a lot of links, why not just do a `find and replace`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can append the target to all of your links within the "links" div by doing this:

**Javascript:**

```
    window.onload = function(){
        var a = document.getElementById('links').getElementsByTagName('a');
        for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
            a[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
        }
    }
```

or **jQuery:**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#links a').attr('target', '_blank');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that without JS using *base* tag.

```
<base target="_blank">
```

Comment: yes but purpose? `target="_blank"` in <a> tag is enough

Comment: I agree, but in this specific case where the OP wants all links on the page to open in new tab, the solution above is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

By using the `target` property.

For example,

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/aggape/" data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/group.php?id=538358279511007" aria-owns="js_1r" aria-haspopup="true" id="js_1s" target="_blank">Sucesso Empresarial</a>
```

See other options in [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp).